# how to parenthetically modify something which I don't know what it is?

Tags: parentheticals

I'm trying to say something like

"X has something to do with Y (which I don't know what it is)".

Clearly, the expression in the parenthesis is awkward here. I'm trying to parenthetically modify the sentence by stating that I have no idea what Y is. I guess a less awkward way to say would be

"X has something to do with Y (which I've never encountered before)".

However, this does not exactly have the same meaning as what I'm trying to say. I'm trying to say that I have no idea what Y is. Anyone know a less awkward way to say this, while maintaining that original meaning exactly?

Comment: It's awkward because you have *which* and *it*. How about "(but I don't know what that is)" -- in that phrase you only reference "it" once.

Comment: yeah, that works. However, "but I don't know what that is" is a complete sentence. I'm trying to go for something to the effect of: "McDonalds has french fries (which I like)". Is there really no way to do this with the action "not knowing what something is" rather than "like"?

Comment: OK... *which I know nothing about.* The thing is to have either the relative pronoun *which* or a real pronoun like *it,* not both.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The reason it's awkward is that it's a [*wh-* island](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233371/confusion-about-usage-of-who-in-a-relative-clause/233465#233465)

Comment: @AndrewLeach So we want to drop the *it*, but that's no good either ...

Comment: @xdavidliu which I don't know the identity of / which I am completely ignorant of perhaps?

Comment: @xdavidliu How about "which I have no knowledge about?"

Comment: yeah these all work I think, and are close enough to the original meaning.

Comment: If it's "Y" itself (and not the relationship/something to do with) that you don't know then I think you should stick with a "which" clause. Maybe "(which is unknown/unfamiliar to me)" would work.

Comment: Another case of [a Ross constraint being violated](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/173713/15299).

Comment: 'X has something to do with Y (of|about which I know nothing)'

Comment: [with which I am not familiar] should work.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I definitely prefer (which is unknown/unfamiliar to me). (of which I know nothing/am not familiar) works well too, though the phrase "of which" in general strikes me as little bit highfalutin for my tastes : )