# Is this sentence correct? Nobody wants to pay for something they are not certain whether they will like it or not

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> Nobody wants to pay for something they are not certain whether they will like it or not.

In particular is the pronoun *it*, correct. If not, how can I correctly formulate the sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Give him a box that everyone knows what it contains."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173696/give-him-a-box-that-everyone-knows-what-it-contains)

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence contains a [reduced relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause) (in other words, the relative pronoun *which* or *that* has been omitted). Expanded it reads:

> Nobody wants to pay for something **that** they are not certain whether they will like it or not.

Embedded within the relative clause is another clause (*whether they will like it or  not)* which contains the pronoun *it*. The *it* in this case refers back to the relative pronoun *that*. This type of repeated pronoun is called a *[resumptive pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun)*.

Resumptive pronouns are a feature of some languages, but are considered ungrammatical in formal English contexts. Therefore, you need to omit *it* so that your sentence reads:

> Nobody wants to pay for something they are not certain whether they will like or not

Comment: Nobody wants to pay for something they might not like.

Comment: I don't find your last sentence entirely grammatical. It's a bit squiffy to me, in fact worse than the OP's.  I think it's one of those places where there's no good way to make the relative clause, a bit like * *Which tournament does Bob have brothers who play in?*

Comment: @Michael Harvey. Your version is a certainly a more concise and less contentious way than the OP's to convey the intended meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria. Squiffiness (squiffidity?) is clearly in the ear of the beholder! How does it sound to you if the relative pronoun is restored and the resumptive pronoun retained: _Nobody wants to pay for something that they are not certain whether they will like it or not_?