# A questionable sentence involving relative pronoun

Tags: sentence

I found the following sentence grammatically questionable:

The Eclipse can reveal an entirely new path that we weren’t aware **it was an option**.

I think it should be,

The Eclipse can reveal an entirely new path that we weren’t aware **was an option**.

Source:
https://www.unpretzelyourbrain.com/sagittarius-full-moon-lunar-eclipse-june/?fbclid=IwAR1D5i5sktnFioIr5jSKh4vJ37miu18ShnXNVDAe2bICd-fhli1uuP5nb0M

Comment: You don't actually ***need*** either the relativiser ***that*** OR the pronoun: *[It] can reveal an entirely new path we weren’t aware was an option* is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Give him a box that everyone knows what it contains."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173696/give-him-a-box-that-everyone-knows-what-it-contains) John Lawler discusses Ross constraint violations.

Comment: @Edwin Thanks for the information.