# What it the right choice?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, objects

Which of the following statements is correct and why?

In other words, is it OK if we bring "it" or if used, it would be redundant and grammatically wrong?

> 1. It is used for an action that we know "it" will happen...
> 2. It is used for an action that we know will happen...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Give him a box that everyone knows what it contains."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173696/give-him-a-box-that-everyone-knows-what-it-contains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four valid constructions are...

> 1: *It is used for an action we know will happen*
> 2: *It is used for an action **that** we know will happen*
> 3: *It is used for an action **where** we know it will happen*
> 4: *It is used for an action **where** we know **that** it will happen*

...where #2 and #4 are effectively the same syntax as #1 and #3 respectively (they just happen to be contexts where the relativiser ***that*** is completely optional). But these are the ***invalid*** permutations...

> 5: *It is used for an action we know it will happen*      - NOT VALID
> 6: *It is used for an action that we know it will happen*   - NOT VALID
> 7: *It is used for an action we know that it will happen*   - NOT VALID

---

It may be useful to discard the "we know" element in OP's examples. Whatever "it" is, presumably it ***will*** happen, regardless of whether we know that or not...

> 8: *It is used for an action that will happen*
> 9: *It is used for an action **where** it will happen*

Note that these are the *only* syntactically valid variations without "we know". And I may be mistaken, but offhand I can't think of a valid context where the two uses of the pronoun "it" in #3, #4, #9 (the ***where*** versions) both refer to the same thing. I'm pretty sure they'd always have to be (contextually established) *different* things.

Comment: Nicely said, the reason you added in the last paragraph was exactly the same thing I did on my own... But since I heard an English teacher using #1 (in my original post) I thought, there might be a point that I'm not aware of. That's why I came here to ask my question...

Comment: Ooop! While you were writing that comment, I was adding an ***additional*** "last paragraph"! I hope it's sorted you out though!

Comment: Your example #1 doesn't look like anything a *native speaker* would be likely to say, so I assume your English teacher in't in fact a native Anglophone (unless perhaps you misheard; it would be fine with ***where, when,*** or ***if*** instead of ***that***). Or perhaps it was a simple slip of the pen when writing it (for example, I definitely intended the first word of my previous comment to be ***Ooops!*** - I've no idea how that ***s*** got lost! Mistakes happen to the best of us!).

Answer (score 1):

The restrictive clause *that we know will happen* describes what type of action "it" is used for. *that* here introduces the restrictive clause and gives us further information about *the action*.

If you want the second sentence to make sense, you would have to drop *that* and insert a different word there. Of course, the meanings of these two sentences might differ vastly.