# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "We are supporting troops that we don't even know who they are."

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> We are supporting troops that we don't even know who they are.

I hear it from a video on Youtube, where Trump was debating with someone.

Comment: No, it's not grammatical. Good ear. [It's a violation of a Ross Constraint](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/173713/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks a lot! This's exactly the mistake point of this sentense in my opinion.

Comment: Oddly enough, a speaker 'New Standard Greek' would recognise this.  Hyposterizoume strateymata pou den xeroume poioi einai [υποστηρίζουμε στρατευματα που δεν ξερουμε ποιοι ειναι.  'Pou' has many functions equivalent to sometimes 'where' (the original ancient meaning, sometimes 'who' or 'which'.  'poioi' is the nominative masculine plural of the actual pronoun.